# Add data from one table into another with same column names

Tags: sql

I have found numerous examples here, on YouTube, and in general Google searches but I'm still hitting a wall. I have two databases with (I believe) identical tables, structure, etc.

db1.dbo.table has a lot more information than does db2.dbo.table. I want to copy SOME of the information from db1.dbo.table into the already-created db2.dbo.table (which has some existing values I would like to keep).

Here's an example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE TYPE = '1'
```

If I run that against db1.dbo.table, it returns a value of 12 rows. When run against db2.dbo.table, it ruturns 2 rows. I want to KEEP those two rows, but then add the other 12 rows from db1.dbo.table.

If I use:

```
select * into db2.dbo.table from db1.dbo.table
```

I get the error that the table already exists.

If I try the following:

```
Use db1
go
insert into table
select *
from table
where type (this is one of my column names) = '1' (one of the appropriate values)
```

I receive "An explicit value for the identity column in table 'table' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON." In researching that, I've tried the following:

```
Set Identity_Insert table (the name of my table) ON
Go
Insert into db2.dbo.table(column 1,column2,etc.,)
select (here, I've tried * as well as the same column1,column2,etc., values as above)
From db1.dbo.table
```

I've still not hit on the correct combination. I'd say I'm still a novice at SQL, but I understand technology and I comprehend what is happening in the examples I read/attempt to edit and execute for my environment, I'm just not sure of how to properly troubleshoot. I will restate below what I want to accomplish.

I want to copy values returned from:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TYPE = '1' in db1 (returns 12 rows)
into db2 (where the same returns 2 rows, I want this to return the same 2, plus the 12 from the other db when I'm done).
```

Comment: What `dbms` are you using? What is the structure of the tables? Check for column types and order of columns between your `insert` and `select` queries. Also see [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of SELECT INTO, try to INSERT INTO:

```
INSERT INTO 
    db2.dbo.table 
        (
        col1, 
        col2, 
        col3, 
        etc.
        )
    SELECT 
        col1, 
        col2, 
        col3, 
        etc. 
    FROM 
        db1.dbo.table
    WHERE 
        TYPE = '1'
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it worked. I ran into a "FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint" when attempting to import one of the three 'TYPE' values, but was able to figure that one out. In my case, I just had to remove one of the fields.

Answer (score -2):

> when you just want to copy and paste all columns data from one table to another and both table has same columns then use this query

```
insert into `WorkerClone` select * from `Worker`;
```

Comment: Answers that contain only code are generally considered poor quality. Apart from that, I don't see how your answer is any different from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49244357/add-data-from-one-table-into-another-with-same-column-names/49244653#49244653). Can you explain what your answer contains that is not contained in the accepted answer? Your answer says to use INSERT..SELECT. The accepted answer says the exact, same thing.

Comment: I have added context to it now . @Abra